# Find a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ such that $ \|Ax\|_{2}=\|x\|_{2}$ for every $ x\in \mathbb{R}^2 $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

How to find a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, $A\neq I_{2}$ such that for every $ x\in \mathbb{R}^2$ we have $\|Ax\|_{2}=\|x\|_{2}$.
Is that even possible?

Comment: What about $A = -I_2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, for example, take $ A $ to be a rotation matrix, in other words any matrix of the form

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} $$

We can check directly that the norm is conserved. Let $ x = (a, b)^T $, then we have

$$ Ax = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} = (a\cos \theta - b \sin \theta, a \sin \theta + b \cos \theta)^T $$

Taking norms, we have

$$ (a \cos \theta - b\sin \theta)^2 + (a \sin \theta + b\cos \theta)^2 = a^2 + b^2 $$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Pick any matrix with orthonormal column vectors.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, we can show more - that every matrix $A$ which preserves the lengths of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a rotation or a reflection.